# keeping the listview item selected while changing tabs

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listview, when i select an item and move to other tab, the selection is not working. basically i need to get the selected item, but i can't.

it shows that no item is in the listview:

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
{
   string IpAdr = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
}
```

it doesn't go inside, which means there are no items.

is changing between tabs causes this problem?

i tried to invoke also, nothing works:

```
 if (this.listView1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                string IpAdress = GetCurrentItem(0);
            }
```

this is how items added to listview:

```
public void AddDiscoveryEntry(object o)
    {
        //lstDiscoveredDevices.Items.Add(o);
        if (o.ToString().Length > 30)
        {

            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(((string)(o)).Split('\n')));

        }

    }
```

and

```
 listView1.Invoke(new AddTolstDiscoveredDevices(AddDiscoveryEntry), ReceiveString);
```

Comment: Check your code, when and how are the items added?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata , this is how is added: `listView1.Invoke(new AddTolstDiscoveredDevices(AddDiscoveryEntry), ReceiveString);`

Comment: Are you sure the items are added before the check?

Comment: the items are added, then i select them to retrieve or access, but there is no items. it is weird!.

Comment: So you have populated `ListView` with static collection `listView1.Items.Count > 0`. Then you switch the tab and suddenly `listView1.Items.Count == 0` ? Looks like your fault totally, search for `listView1.Clear()` and `listView1.Items.Clear()`.

Comment: @Sinatr, i didnt get your response. why we need to clear the `listview` while we are trying to get the selected item?

Comment: Just patiently step through your code one by one, you'll see where the error is.

Comment: the problem was when i move to other tab. inside the tab, i can get the item from the listview, but not the other. i have no idea the reason behind it.

Comment: I've tested my code and it seems to work OK. Do you have any code executed when switching between tabpages?

Comment: @KingKing the button that gets the items in listviw is on the other tabpage. is that the case for you also, or you have the button on the same page as the listview?

Comment: @Liban ah, I have a button on another tabpage than the one containing the listview. Clicking that button showed me the correct `ListView.Items.Count` or even `ListView.SelectedItems[0].Text`

Comment: @KingKing, then something wrong with my code, because when i moved the button on the same tabpage it worked.

Comment: @Liban that's why I asked you if you had any code executed between tabpage switches. You may want to try debugging and find out what it is.